# Create custom template for just one category

Tags: magento-1.7, category, layout, layout-update

I would like to map one specific category to a different phtml file in my theme. Hoping to do this without creating a sub-theme for just one file.

ALMOST have it... but need some help:

I put the following into Category > Custom Design > Custom Layout Update

```
<reference name="content">
     <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view_madeby.phtml" /> 
</reference>
```

**This works,** but it's outputting the contents of view_madeby.phtml twice when I view the category. Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Category.products" block is outputting twice, because you are adding it second time. Instead it just change block template:

```
<reference name="category.products">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>catalog/category/view_madeby.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```